# What cron jobs should be running for magento2

Tags: magento2

Can someone please confirm what cron jobs should be running as standard, for Magento 2.
I keep getting a indexer error, even though I have set it up. I somehow think the error may be coming from another cron, that is conflicting.
If i delete all and start again, may help?
The screenshot shows current listed in cPanel.
cPanel screenshot--

[image]

Comment: those have to run every minute

Comment: shared hosting. They request no more than every 30 mins, or they will reset them. Does that make a difference? Is this is why i get the error?